# How to index pandas DataFrames by selecting times in a particular interval?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame in a similar layout to the following:

```
In [24]: example_df
Out[24]:
                      Price
DateTime
2012-09-11 19:44:00   99.622
2012-09-11 19:45:00   99.312
2012-09-11 19:46:00   99.211
2012-09-11 19:47:00   99.757
2012-09-11 19:48:00   99.312
2012-09-11 19:49:00   99.157
2012-09-11 19:50:00   99.751
...
```

The DataFrame has a datetime index.

This DataFrame spans many years minute by minute, how would I go about slicing the data to only contain a certain time period from every day in the time series? Say 12:00-13:00 for every single day in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`indexer_between_time()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) to capture the indices lying in a given time intervals and then `iloc` to slice the DataFrame. For example:

```
>>> df.iloc[df.index.indexer_between_time('19:45:00', '19:49:00')]
                      Price
2012-09-11 19:45:00  99.312
2012-09-11 19:46:00  99.211
2012-09-11 19:47:00  99.757
2012-09-11 19:48:00  99.312
2012-09-11 19:49:00  99.157
```

For your specific request of entries between 12:00 to 13:00 for every single day, you can fetch the rows with:

```
df.iloc[df.index.indexer_between_time('12:00:00', '13:00:00')]
```

Comment: This works great, thanks, quick question though - df.index.indexer_between_time('12:00:00', '13:00:00') gives a array of indices - how does pandas iloc then parse this list? Simply two at a time?

Comment: Glad it helped - `iloc` just goes through the array of integers and selects each corresponding row from the DataFrame (do let me know if I've misunderstood your question).